# Topological Sorting using Kahn's Algorithm

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph

I wanted to know ,what does the following part of code mean ,
I understood the whole function but the `for loop at the end` is making me confused and not able to understand.
So please tell  me what it is doing there?

```
void topologicalSort(vector<int> adj[], int V) 
{ 
    vector<int> in_degree(V, 0); 
  
    for (int u = 0; u < V; u++) { 
        for (int x:adj[u]) 
            in_degree[x]++; 
    } 
  
    queue<int> q; 
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) 
        if (in_degree[i] == 0) 
            q.push(i); 

  
    while (!q.empty()) { 
        int u = q.front(); 
        q.pop(); 
        cout<<u<<" "; 
  
        for (int x: adj[u]) 
            if (--in_degree[x] == 0) 
                q.push(x); 
    } 
}
```

This the link to whole code https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/PSNw3VplJL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kahn's algoritm (which has nothing to do with BFS):

1. Find all the vertexes with in-degree 0 and put them in a queue (`q` in your code).
2. Pick a vertex from the queue, output it, and delete it from the graph.
3. Deleting the vertex will reduce the in-degree of all its neighbors.  Some of these could reach in-degree 0 -- put those ones in the queue.
4. Go back to 2 until you're out of vertexes.

That last for loop does step (3).